# Algorithm to distribute boxes within a fixed space

Tags: algorithm, layout

I have a number of boxes of arbitrary width. The width of each box may be constrained by a lower and upper bound. Now I want to stack these boxes to fit inside a fixed amount of space, using these rules:

1. There can be no empty space left.
2. The width of each box can be changed within its bounds.
3. The widths of all boxes should be as uniform as possible.

As a precondition, it is assumed that not all boxes are constrained in a way to rule out a solution.

For example, let's say I have 460 units of available space and five boxes. One box has a lower bound of 200, and one box has both a lower and an upper bound of 20. After distributing these boxes inside the available space, the result looks like this:

[image: Sample distribution]

The black numbers in this example are given, and the blue numbers are the expected result. I am looking for an algorithm that produces this result. Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Hate being that guy, but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Binary search between 0 and `w`(=460 in your example). Let's call it `target-w`.

  - For each box, if `target-w` falls inside `[w_min, w_max]`, use `target-w` as the chosen width for the box. Otherwise, choose either `w_min` or `w_max` as appropriate.
  - Sum up the chosen width for all the boxes.
  - If the sum is larger than `w`, we need a smaller `target-w`. Otherwise, we need a smaller `target-w`.
  - (Continue with the binary search.)